# Navigating Date Picker in IE using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer

I'm trying to automate a report of mine and I can't seem to find the right code for entering the start and end date of my reports. I can't post the link since it's a client web based tool.

I have tried setting up the date via getElementByID and it changes the date but it doesn't extract the data (no data at all). When I don't input any date codes at all, it extracts the data for today with no issues.

I think I need to set up the dates via it's date picker to fully extract the data. I hope someone can walk me through that process.

Commented codes are what I've tried so far and attached pics are for the HTML Files.

[Start End Date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SA8OH.png)
[Date Picker Start Date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYsMH.png)

```
Sub Get_RawFile()
    '
    '
    '
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
    Dim HTMLDoc As HTMLDocument
    Dim HTMLselect As HTMLSelectElement

    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate ("--------------------------")

    While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend

    Set HTMLDoc = IE.document
    HTMLDoc.all.UserName.Value = Sheets("Data Dump").Range("A1").Value
    HTMLDoc.all.Password.Value = Sheets("Data Dump").Range("B1").Value
    HTMLDoc.getElementById("login-btn").Click

    While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))

    Set objButton = HTMLDoc.getElementById("s2id_ddlReportType")
    Set HTMLselect = HTMLDoc.getElementById("ddlReportType")
    objButton.Focus
    HTMLselect.Value = "1"

    Set HTMLselectZone = HTMLDoc.getElementById("ddlTimezone")
    HTMLselectZone.Value = Sheets("Data Dump").Range("B9").Value

    Set subgroups = HTMLDoc.getElementById("s2id_ddlSubgroups")
    subgroups.Click
    Set subgroups2 = HTMLDoc.getElementById("ddlSubgroups")
    subgroups2.Value = "1456_17"

    'HTMLDoc.getElementById("dtStartDate").Value = Sheets("Attendance").Range("B6").Value
    'HTMLDoc.getElementById("dtStartDate").Click

    'HTMLDoc.getElementById("dtEndDate").Value = Sheets("Attendance").Range("X6").Value
    'HTMLDoc.getElementById("dtEndDate").Click


       HTMLDoc.getElementById("btnGetReport").Click
       Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"))

       HTMLDoc.getElementById("btnDowloadReport").Click

       End With
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Excel, dates are stored as a decimal value.
I guess your HTML expects a string so try to format :

```vb
HTMLDoc.getElementById("dtStartDate").Value = Format(Sheets("Attendance").Range("B6").Value, "yyyy-mm-dd")
```